# How Blender sets its reference frame?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, axis, transform-orientation

I would like to know how Blender defines its global reference frame, and if it is possible to modify its definition.

By reference point, I mean the x, y and z axes that we can see at any time when we model objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't a lot of ways to describe a reference frame.  There are ways to describe the *relationship* between *two* reference frames; we do this whenever we're thinking about object coordinates vs. world coordinates.  But if we want to describe the orientation of the world, without respect to any other orientation, we're kind of stuck: it has no rotation.  Its origin is 0,0,0.  It has a scale of 1 in all axes.  That's not actually saying anything.

There aren't that many parameters for a coordinate system.  In this case, obviously, we have a three dimensional coordinate system; that's one parameter.  The only other parameter that I can think of here is the **coordinate system handedness**.

Blender uses a right-handed coordinate system.  This is an arbitrary choice and cannot be altered without massive changes to the code.  The other option is a left-handed coordinate system.  The distinguishing feature of this is the orientation of the positive axes.  If we imagine our +X axis pointing to the right, and the +Y axis pointing away from us, then Blender's +Z axis points upwards.  In a left handed coordinate system, the +Z axis would point downwards.  OpenGL based applications, like Blender, use right handed coordinate systems.  DirectX based applications, like most Windows games, use left handed coordinate systems.  Yes, this is unfortunate.

Sometimes, people think that Z means up in Blender, but that's not really the case: all we have to do is revise how we think about things.  If we think about numpad 5 giving us a frontal view instead of numpad 1, then Z is the depth axis.  Some features of Blender-- autonaming, for example-- are going to seem weird when we do that, but we just revise how we're thinking about what we're doing: in this case, .t will mean close and .b will mean far, rather than top and bottom.  And our default gravity vector will be towards "depth", but of course, we can change that vector.

However, no matter how we think about our axes, we will never be able to think about our axes differently: if +X is right and +Y is top rather than deep, then +Z is close rather than far.  That is why +X=right is not an intrinsic feature of the coordinate system, but the handedness is.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination
It makes sens now and it is what I was searching

Answer (score 0):

No. However, by theory of relativity, you can achieve the exact same effect by placing the 3D cursor at the origin (Shift+C), setting the transform orientation from “median point” to “3D cursor,” selecting all, and then transforming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But my question was more about how blender defines its reference frame. Do you know a mathematical definition?
For example, I notice that the definition of the x and y axis with Blender corresponds to -x and -y axis with Matlab. I am searching the mathematical definition of the frame/ origin of Blender.

Comment: Umm, the definition of… I’m lost. As far as I know, the choosing of which axis is positive and which one is negative, and what directions they correspond to in the real world, is entirely arbitrary. I think what you’re really asking is, is there a way to change which axes directions are positive and negative, because you’ve learned it one way in a different program and blender is another.

Comment: Yes it is something like that.
Moreover, the rotation between the frames are different.
I would like to characterize this difference (rotations of the axis and their locations). However to do that, I need to know how Blender defines its frame.
It means, mathematically, what is the definition of its frame? Do you know the definition of the origin in term of coordinates, ect?
Sorry if my question is unclear. I do not really how to define it properly.

Comment: Does this help you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221353/73575

Comment: Not really. Here you have the mathematical definition of the camera frame according to the fundamental frame of Blender. What I am searching is the definition of this fundamental frame, namely, if I take this example, you have the rotation of your camera according a fundamental frame defined by Blender before any transformations. My question is do you know how to define, characterises this frame?