# How is matrix_world calculated?

Tags: scripting

I have been searching about this but haven't found any information on this topic, and Blender docs are not very explanatory for *bpy.types.Object.matrix_world*:

> Worldspace transformation matrix
> Type
> float multi-dimensional array of 4 * 4 items in [-inf, inf], default ((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))

My question is: how does Blender calculate this matrix? I can understand the translation part of the matrix, so if I have a camera at (2, 2, 2), the 4th column of the matrix will be (2, 2, 2, 1). But what about the rotation part?

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-3d-matrix-transforms-with-pixijs-c76da3f8bd8   https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2010fa/lectures/03transforms3d.pdf

Comment: Thanks! The Lecture from Cornell was very useful, especially slides 15 and 16. For future reference and for others with this doubt: the world matrix has the form of F in slide 15, and you calculate u, v and w as in s16. You just have to be careful about the axes and what direction you choose as up.

Comment: Nice explanation!